# How to convert e-05 to 0.0000

Tags: awk, sed, curl, jq

When I trying to parse html via curl+jq I see that where it see 0.0000123 it printing for example 1.23e-05.How can I convert this? Or if is so hard please write some sed or awk alternatives.

Comment: See similar question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42956806/5008284), with alternative perl solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most printf implementations could do the conversion:

[dash](/questions/tagged/dash)`printf '%5.4f' 1e-5` ==> `0.0000`
 [ksh](/questions/tagged/ksh)`printf '%7.4f' 1.23e2` ==> `123.0000`
 [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)`printf '%7.5f' 1.2324558e-2` ==> `0.01232`

[awk](/questions/tagged/awk)

```
$ echo 12.34567E-3 | awk '{printf "%5.10f\n", $1}'
0.0123456700
```

[perl](/questions/tagged/perl)

```
$ echo "123.56e-2" | perl -ne 'printf( "%03.7f\n", $_)'
1.2356000
```

[php](/questions/tagged/php)

```
$ cat php01.php
<?php
$number = 123.45678e1;
printf("%10.3f\n",$number);
?>
$ php php01.php 
  1234.568
```

Answer (score 3):

with awk you can do like this :

```
$ echo 123.4567E-05 | awk '{printf "%5.8f\n", $1}'
0.00123457
```

%x.yf determines the output format you want to see.

Then, you you can use your `curl ......pattern....| awk '{printf .........}'`